# C++: Accessing possibly non-existent const vector member - try/catch or if (count != 0)?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, try-catch

I want to assign a copy of a member of a `vector` to another variable, if that member exists. If it doesn't, then no assignment should be made. No changes may be made to the `vector`.

I could do the `try`/`catch` approach, or the `if(exists)`/do approach. Are there reasons to prefer one over the other? i.e. Given this

```
const vector<int> v = {}; // or maybe {1, 2, 5}
int myInt;
```

Traditional conditional approach:

```
if (v.size() >= 2)
{
    myInt = v.at(1);
    // or myInt = v[1];
}
```

Try/catch:

```
try
{
    myInt = v.at(1);
}
catch(std::out_of_range)
{
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `std::vector::operator[]` does *not* do bounds checking!

Comment: @melak47, thus I shouldn't have it as an option in the `try` block - removed. Thanks.

Comment: Exceptions and bound checking introduce a tiny overhead (which is fine most of the time), but if the code is super critical then you may consider using the first approach.

Comment: The traditional approach is simpler and faster, so I would prefer that. If you were actually doing something with the exception, or throwing it out of the function, that would be a different situation.

Answer (score 5):

That mostly depends on your own view of exceptions. The (in my opinion) usual attribute to give them is that "Exceptions should be the exception."

If in normal execution you are going to throw that exception, just because you don't want to write the check for existence, then that would be contrary to that statement above.

The reason for that is mostly that stack unwinding is not always that cheap. Though, probably vector::at would be inlined and there would be no stack to unwind. Maybe the compiler even optimizes that exception away.

It may still be a nuisance if you are debugging vector accesses in general. For example, if you want to catch for all out_of_bounds exceptions to track a nondescript error message, you will have a harder time if you keep throwing those exceptions during normal operation.

Comment: "Stack unwinding is not always that cheap."  For clarification, stack unwinding can easily be hundreds or thousands of times more expensive than an if statement.

Comment: I know - I didn't want to go into detail, because there is obviously not much to after all. And, as that situation may be pretty common in modern c++, there is always a tiny bit of hope that somewhere someone was nice enough to tune the optimizer for it.

Comment: @JA, "if you want to catch for all out_of_bounds exceptions to track a nondescript error message" - can you clarify?

Comment: True, but it also might not be possible to optimize it.  If you allocate an object whose dtor and ctor isn't visible in this translation unit within the block, for instance, it's impossible to simply optimize the try catch block away.

Comment: @cp.engr If somewhere in your program something throws an out_of_bounds exception and you aren't catching it (because for instance, you believe it's not possible for the variable to be out of bounds, so you simply don't check,) then it can be tricky to use a debugger to hunt it down.  Normally, you'd set a break whenever an out_of_bound exception is thrown; however, if you're constantly throwing that exception, then you might have to continue thousands of times before you get to the real error you're trying to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it depends on the consequences "if no assignment is made".

Can your code that is attempting to access `v[1]` deal appropriately `v.size()` is `1` or less?   For example, by resizing `v` on the spot, giving some default value to your variable.      In that case, it is not necessary to throw an exception - the caller does not even need to be bothered with a potential error condition, since it will be corrected.

Is your code unable to correct for `v.size()` being `1` or less, but there is a reasonable likelihood that a caller will be able to recover?   If the caller can be reasonably expected to check and recover, then a return code is appropriate (no exception needs be thrown).    Similarly, if the caller can reasonably continue normally if an error occurs but it doesn't check, then again a return code is appropriate.   If the caller cannot reasonably be expected to recover, or if the caller can recover but can't be relied on to check the error condition, it is better to throw an exception - which either forces the caller to handle the error, or be terminated.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually the question: "If it doesn't, then no assignment should be made. No changes may be made to the vector." He does not want the exception to propagate down the stack, he directly wants to catch it, no questions asked.

Comment: @JA, maybe I made the question more narrow than I meant to. Or maybe I just hadn't considered if throwing an exception up the chain may be useful now, or in other situations. Either way, this is useful info to me.

Comment: I have actually answered the question, J.A.   I just answered in a broader context than you did.

Comment: @JA & Peter, I wish I could accept both your answers - can't choose, both valuable. I upvoted both, anyway.